# Is application alive ? android (Handler issue)

Tags: android, android-activity, android-handler

```
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                if (MainTab.isRunning == true)
                    ;
                {
                    Dialog.show();
                }
            }
        }, Sec * 1000);
```

isRunning is a variable and in my activity whenever it calls onStop or onPause method it becomes false. However it's not working, even if I close my app Dialog still wants to add a window and I'm getting errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the extra `;`:

```
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                if (MainTab.isRunning == true)
                {
                    Dialog.show();
                }
            }
        }, Sec * 1000);
```

It causes your if statement to become useless, as it instructs java to interpret the next line as a new instruction, instead of as a part of the if statement.

Answer (score 0):

Your callback will still execute even though it does nothing now, this is unnecessary. You should just cancel the callback with [`removeCallbacksAndMessages()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#removeCallbacksAndMessages%28java.lang.Object%29) in `onPause()`:

```
handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
```

Or save a reference to your runnable and call `handler.removeCallback(runnable)`.